# CSS challenge: Using two div and contenteditable div to Create a 凸 shape

Tags: html, css

[image][image]I want to create something like the picture, where the #body is between #leg1 and #leg2, three of them should be horizontally in line to the bottom. Any idea how to achieve this? I tweaked some property such as `display:inline`, or `float:left`, `float:right`, but none of them work as I expect.

```css
.comment_leg {
  s width: 60px;
  /*height:18px;*/
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  For Firefox
}
#body {
  background-color: white;
  /*position:relative;*/
  border: 1px solid orange;
  /*height:60px;*/
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 18px;
  /*border-color:yellow;*/
}
#body:focus {
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: orange;
  outline-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="comment_leg">leg1</div>
<div id="body" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Pika pi?"></div>
<div class="comment_leg">leg2</div>
```

Comment: How do you horizontally align something to the bottom?!

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you'd like (something more understandable then 凸)

Comment: I mean they should be something looks like       _  _______ _

Comment: https://codepen.io/blazeeboy/pen/bCaLE

Comment: `display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3d8jd5xv/

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood of your "凸" shape I guess this is what you want:

NOTE: You can adjust `height` and `width` depending on your preference.

```css
.comment_leg {
  width: 60px;
  /*height:18px;*/
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;

  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
}
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  For Firefox
}
#body {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  min-height:100px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 18px;

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#body:focus {
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: orange;
  outline-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment_leg">leg1</div>
<div id="body" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Pika pi?"></div>
<div class="comment_leg">leg2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the contenteditable div doesn't  in line with legs when typing in multiple lines.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, can you explain it please?

Comment: I have uploaded a screen shot on the question.

Comment: That's what I wrote the note that says that you can change height and width depending on your preference, I gave a fixed 100px height, If you want it to increase as you type in there set it to min-height or if you want to start from what the content's height is just don't set the height. I edited it now to increase as you write in but start from 100px.

Comment: Mark it as answer then haha with the green check.

Comment: The cursor is slightly bigger than the div, any quick suggestions to make it smaller? The min-height makes the cursor bigger as well

Comment: @战斗人员 Remove the `[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {}` rule.  Tried in Chrome, FF, and IE and only get the issue in Chrome.

Comment: if removed, the placeholder text also disapeared.